# Is there a more efficient way to write these 4 MYSQL Queries to use fewer queries?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

My current queries. Can I combine them in to fewer to get the same result? I am trying to get specific information about the trail into an array named $trail.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'location_city' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$trail[city] = $result[0];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'length' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);       
$trail[length] = $result[0];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'location_state' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$trail[state] = $result[0];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND `meta_key` = 'difficulty' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$trail[difficulty] = $result[0];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_parent` = $id AND `post_type` = 'attachment' ");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$trail[image] = $result[0];
```

Comment: yes, use OR or IN for meta_key

Comment: Have you tried to merge the queries? If so show us what you tried. What you are asking to do is technically possible. Furthermore the performance of 4 queries vs 1 would depend entirely on the indexes you have set. Generally primary key lookups are very quick so you won't see a huge different in performance.

Comment: You should switch to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right now and then fix all the notices. For example, quote your array keys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data in columns, then you could `JOIN` the queries:

```
SELECT lc.meta_value Location_City,
    l.meta_value Location,
    ls.meta_value LocationState,
    d.meta_value Difficulty,
    p.guid
FROM wp_postmeta lc
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta l
    on lc.`post_id` = l.`post_id`
    and l.`meta_key` = 'length'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ls
    on lc.`post_id` = ls.`post_id`
    and ls.`meta_key` = 'location_state'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta d
    on lc.`post_id` = d.`post_id`
    and d.`meta_key` = 'difficulty'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p
    on lc.`post_id` = p.`post_parent`
    and p.`post_type` = 'attachment'
WHERE lc.`post_id` = $id 
    AND lc.`meta_key` = 'location_city'
```

Comment: So far this works perfectly! I'm going to put it into practice and tweak it, I'll report back if it's fully working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will work for the meta_values:

```
SELECT meta_value, meta_key
...
WHERE (post_id = $id) AND (meta_key IN ('location_city', 'length', ...)
```

The guid query will probably be better off run as a separate one. If you insist on reducing to a single query call, then a union would do

```
SELECT 'meta' AS source, meta_value, meta_key
WHERE ...

UNION ALL

SELECT 'guid' AS source, guid, null
FROM ...
WHERE post_parent = $id and post_type = 'attachment'
```

then use this derived 'source' field to figure out which value(s) belong where.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works. It only returns one "meta_value" and "meta_key"... See here http://pastebin.com/e9tFsHzr

Comment: well, yeah.. you're not calling fetch in a loop, so you'll only ever retrieve one row.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: naw. that's not ignorance. inexperience, maybe. everyone's entitled to a few mistakes... [stern look] just don't do it again! [/stern]. heh

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = $id AND (`meta_key` = 'difficulty' OR `meta_key` = 'location_state' OR `meta_key` = 'length'  OR `meta_key` = 'location_city' )
```